# How to inject things on objects that were created using reflection?

Tags: java, guice, code-injection

A simple example:

```
class C{}

class B{
    @Inject C c;
    void doSomething(){
         System.out.println(c);
    }
}

class A{
    @Inject A(B b){
        b.doSomething();//this works fine and prints the c object
    }
}
```

Now, if I create the B object using reflection:

```
class A{
     A(){
         // blah blah blah 
         B b = constructor.newInstance();
         b.doSomething(); // sigh, this prints null!!!
     }
}
```

So, my question is: how can I make the injection work if I have created the B object using reflection (rather than injection via Guice)?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to create `B` by reflection instead of having it injected?

Comment: Well, I think I simplify a lot the example. B is created by a factory... the factory knows how to create complex objects which cannot be injected easily: all they have different kind of constructors and in order to make Guice work fine I'd need to use assisted injection, which is not supported by the Guice version for Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inject a `MembersInjector<B>` and use that to inject the fields and methods of `B`:

```
class A {
    @Inject A(MembersInjector<B> bInjector) {
        ...
        B b = constructor.newInstance();
        bInjector.injectMembers(b);
        b.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The best part of this approach is that Guice can prepare the bindings for B ahead of time. If there will be problems injecting B, you'll find out when you create the injector, which is usually application startup. This is preferred over `Injector.injectMembers()` because that won't fail until it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `injector.injectMembers(myObject)`, but I doubt this follows best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Either/or: you can put it under the DI engine's control or take it on yourself, but it's hard to have both.

The only way I can think of is to tell the DI engine about a factory method that might use reflection to create the instance.  But that's the only mechanism that would come to mind.